# How to combine GTM default macros and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have been playing around with GTM for some time, but now I got stuck.

I need to get parent div of clicked element () which contains H4 tag -- and then take text within H4 and pass it 'Event Action'.

So far I have setup click listener, but I am not sure how to use {{element}} within as jQuery selector?

Any tips/ideas? Or am I doing this completely wrong? :-)

Below is DOM structure that illustrates what gets clicked and what I need to grab by GTM macro:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how JQuery would fit into this, but you can grab that value with a custom macro (of Data Layer type in GTM). You can go up and down the DOM starting with `gtm.element`, which is the element that is clicked on. Does something like this work for data variable name?

`gtm.element.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.firstChild.innerText`

Kind of specific to your exact situation, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of the same thing as @wils484, but thought I would do something a bit more flexible:

```
function(){

    //define element that was clicked
    var element      = {{gtm.element}};

    //define class
    var elementClass = 'border-box';

    /*go up the DOM tree and as long as there are still elements and
     *they do not contain the class name that contains our elementClass
     *that holds our h4 tag, keep moving. This should be good to go 
     *for earlier IE's.
     */

    while(element && !((" " + element.className + " ").indexOf(" " + elementClass + " ") > -1)){

        element = element.parentNode;
    }

    //find our h4 tag and grab the innerText, or if IE, grab textContent
    return element.querySelector('h4').innerText || element.querySelector('h4').textContent;
}
```

I'm newer to js and spent some time on this this past week, and even posted a bounty for trying to figure out how to find the class. There are some alternative options in that post [Check for class in element in while loop in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225882/check-for-class-in-element-in-while-loop-in-javascript), but felt that the response I got from @Greg Burghardt (slightly tweaked for earlier versions of IE) made the most since for GTM.