# Check for class in element in while loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

*This has to be done in javascript, not jQuery.

What I'm trying to do is grab the `innerText` of the `h4` tag when `<a>` with the class `btn-blue` is clicked.

I realize that I could do:

```
element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].innerText;
```

but I'm really wanting something more flexible.

This is what I have so far, and it does work when I run it in the console (chrome), but as soon as I add it to the site, it doesn't pull in the innerText of the h4 tag.

**HTML**

```
<div class="border-box clearfix">
    <div class="blah">
        <h4>h4 Title</h4>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div class="head clearfix">
        <h4>h4 Title</h4>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <p class="float-right">
        <a href="/transactions/" class="btn-blue">anchor tag</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('head')[0];
    var parent = el.parentElement;

    while(parent && parent !== document.body && parent.className && parent.className.indexOf('head'){
        parent = parent.previousElementSibling;
    }

    var children = parent.childNodes;

        for(i=0; i < children.length; i++){
            var name = children[i].tagName;
                if(name.toLowerCase() === 'h4'){
                    var text = children[i].innerText || children[i].textContent;
                        return text;
                }
        }
```

I believe the issue is with using `parent.className.indexOf('head')` in the while loop. What I'm trying to determine is if the element has the class of head, and from the SO questions ([javascript - Test if an element contains a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)), I've seen I can do indexOf to check and see if head is within the class.

I've also read that I can use `.classList.contains('head')`, but that doesn't include support for earlier IE browsers.

Two questions:

1. Am I getting the `innerText` of the `<h4>` tag in the best possible way? (this could be better suited for codereview.stackoverflow.com).
2. What the best way to test if a element has a class within a while loop?

**SOLUTION:**

I ended up using @Greg Burghardt 's solution solely because it was the easiest for me to tweak and implement for use in Google Tag Manager. The final code looked like this:

```
function(){
    var element   = {{gtm.element}};
    var elementClass = 'border-box';

    while(element && !((" " + element.className + " ").indexOf(" " + elementClass + " ") > -1)){
        element = element.parentNode;
    }

    return element.querySelector('h4').innerText || element.querySelector('h4').textContent;
}
```

Comment: If anyone would like to play around he may fork [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yBbY73AIhv55wfu0ehNy?p=preview).

Comment: Will the `HTML` be always similar the one in your post? (I mean the hierarchy). Are there going to be 1 or multiple `anchor` tags in your page?

Comment: @W.D. there will be multiple `anchor` tags throughout the page. Think of the `HTML` block I've provided as a one blog post out of a blog roll (multiple blog post summaries). That make sense?

Comment: I've written a code which works in IE8 as well. I'll post it. Take a look at it. I'll post an example on `jsfiddle`, but the latter has no support of IE8 whatsoever. However my code works in IE8 (just tested it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
function findHeaderText(element, className) {
    while (element && !element.classList.contains(className)) {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }

    var heading = element.querySelector("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"),
        text = heading.innerHTML;

    return text;
}


function handleClick(event) {
    var text = findHeaderText(event.target, "border-box");

    alert(text);
}
```

The basic idea is to start at the target of the click event, and walk up the document tree until you find an element containing a certain class. From there, use the `querySelector` method to grab the first heading, then grab its innerHTML or text.

The function could probably use some additional error handling, but I leave that as an exercise for you. :)

Comment: Yeah, but you're using classList which isn't support for IE 8/9.

Comment: So replace that function call with a regular express or string test. No biggie.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code. This might seem a bit extended, but it does the job!

If you need explanation, I'll provide it!

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DpjjJ/1/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="border-box clearfix">
    <div class="blah">
        <h4>h4 Title</h4>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div class="head clearfix">
        <h4>h4 Title</h4>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <p class="float-right">
        <a href="#" onclick='return false' class="btn-blue">anchor tag</a>
    </p>
</div>


<div class="border-box clearfix">
    <div class="blah">
        <h4>h4 Title</h4>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div class="head clearfix">
        <h4>h4 Title2</h4>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <p class="float-right">
        <a href="#" onclick='return false' class="btn-blue">anchor tag</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   function attach_(element,listener,ev,tf){

    if(element.attachEvent) {

        element.attachEvent("on"+listener,ev);

        }else{

        element.addEventListener(listener,ev,tf);

        }

    }

function getCls(clsNm){

    return clS = document.querySelectorAll ? document.querySelectorAll("."+clsNm) : document.getElementsByClassName(clsNm);

    }


function returnH4Text(el){

    wrapper = el.parentNode.parentNode;

    divs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div');

    if(divs.length>0){

    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){

        if(divs[i].className.match('head')){

            return h4Text = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerText ? divs[i].getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerText : divs[i].getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].textContent;

            }

        }

    }

    }

var anchors = getCls('btn-blue');

if(anchors.length>0){

    for(var y=0;y<anchors.length;y++){

attach_(anchors[y],'mousedown',function(event){

    evt = event || window.event;
    trg = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    alert(returnH4Text(trg));

    },false);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use prototype style. This OO style is easier to use and understand. But unfortunately, you can't add prototype to Element before IE8. So this solution only support IE8+ and other browsers. If you want to support IE7, you can try to change it to functional style.
http://jsfiddle.net/Wa629/

```
Element.prototype.getParentByClassName = function(className) {
    if(!this.parentNode)
        return null;
    else if(this.parentNode.hasClass(className))
        return this.parentNode;
    else
        return this.parentNode.getParentByClassName(className);
};

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
    return (this.classList || this.className.split(' ')).contains(className);
};

Element.prototype.text = function() {
    return this.innerText || this.textContent;
};

if(!Array.prototype.contains)
{
    Array.prototype.contains = function(item) {
        for(var i = 0;i < item.length;++i)
            if(this[i] == item)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use following way to get title:

```
element.getParentByClassName('border-box').querySelector('.head h4').text()
```